# Linq error generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type

Tags: linq, null

I got this error when i use sum function in LINQ:

> The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

```
GroupProduct.Where(a => a.Product.ProductID==1).Sum(Content => Content.Amount==null?0:Content.Amount),
```

Comment: What is the data type of the Amount property ?

Comment: DefaultIfempty is a must to use, in case the Where does not return any value, thus avoiding NULL in that case.

Answer (score 15):

This is what I usually use. This will cover the possibility of `Amount` being null and also cover the possibility of an empty set.

```
GroupProduct.Where(a => a.Product.ProductID == 1)
    .Select(c => c.Amount ?? 0) // select only the amount field
    .DefaultIfEmpty()  // if selection result is empty, return the default value
    .Sum(c => c)
```

`DefaultIfEmpty()` returns the default value associated with `Amount`'s type, which is `int`, in which case the default value is `0`.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: thanks for fixing the typos in my response.
BUT I put back the null coalescing operator.
DefaultIfEmpty will return a single 0 entry ONLY IF the initial result set is empty, If it's not empty but the Amount happens to nullable and has a null value it will fail without the null coalescing operator.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try the following:

```
GroupProduct.Where(a => a.Product.ProductID==1).Sum(Content => (decimal?)Content.Amount)
```

The code from my application looks like:

```
var data = query.AsEnumerable().Select(row => TaskInfo.FetchTaskInfo(row,
      ctx.ObjectContext.Hours.Where(hour => hour.TaskId == row.TaskId).Sum(hour => (decimal?)hour.Duration),
      ctx.ObjectContext.Notes.Count(note => note.SourceType == (int)SourceType.Task && note.SourceId == row.TaskId)));
```

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty before Sum is a must if there's no item returned on the 1st place.

Answer (score 4):

You could exclude at source?

```
var sum = GroupProduct.Where(a => a.Product.ProductID==1 && a.Amount != null)
            .Sum(a => (decimal)a.Amount);
```

Comment: @malik - I don't understand; can you re-phrase that comment?

Comment: Thank you again:

There are two things.

when i use a.Product.ProductID the object is null, can i check it in linq query.

Comment: I mean in lamda expression can i load the reference and can i handle null in linq query.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var sum = GroupProduct.Where(a => a.Product.ProductID==1).Sum(Content => (int?) Content.Amount);
sum = sum ?? 0;
```

Comment: Yes, this is another way to solve by allowing nullable types inside the LINQ and do a null coalesce on the end. IMO the DefaultIfEmpty is the proper solution, cause we do expect a number as result at the end, not a nullable result.

Answer (score 1):

This **looks** like it should work (and usually does) but fails when the Where() method returns null:

```
decimal sum1 = GroupProduct
    .Where(a => a.Product.ProductID == 1)
    .Sum(c => c.Amount ?? 0);
```

The error: `"The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null"` is due to the Sum() method returning null (not zero) when summing over an empty set.

Either of these work for me:

```
decimal? sum2 = GroupProduct
    .Where(a => a.Product.ProductID == 1)
    .Sum(c => c.Amount);

decimal sum3 = GroupProduct
    .Where(a => a.Product.ProductID == 1)
    .Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0;
```

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty before Sum is a must if there's no item returned on the 1st place.