# Exception when using LINQ SUM

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get the SUM of "bookings" and I get error "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

```
var bookings = entities.Bookings.Where(x => x.ID == id &&
                                     x.StartDate <= bookingEnd &&
                                     x.EndDate >= bookingStart)
                                    .Sum(x => x.BookingQuantity);
```

How shall I fix this? I need to get 0 if it ever gets to be null else its bookings.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076827/linq-error-generic-parameter-or-the-query-must-use-a-nullable-type

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try the null coalescing operator:

```
var bookings = entities.Bookings.Where(x => x.ID == id &&
                                 x.StartDate <= bookingEnd &&
                                 x.EndDate >= bookingStart && 
                                 x.BookingQuantity != null)
                                .Sum(x => (int?)x.BookingQuantity) ?? 0;
```

or declare bookings as a nullable int

int? bookings = ...

The compilers type inference is picking up the result of Sum as a plain int, which should never be null.

Comment: In my case it also returns int, not nullable int which doesn't make sense. How does the ?? 0 fix it then?

Answer (score 15):

[This page](http://adventuresinsoftware.com/blog/?m=201001) suggests a fix to this problem;

```
Sum(x => (int?)x.BookingQuantity) ?? 0;
```

Comment: my compiler throws an error saying '?? cannot be applied to type int'

Comment: Did you cast it to (int?) ?

Answer (score 1):

Add checking for null.

```
var bookings = entities.Bookings.Where(x => x.ID == id &&
                                     x.StartDate <= bookingEnd &&
                                     x.EndDate >= bookingStart && 
                                     x.BookingQuantity != null)
                                    .Sum(x => x.BookingQuantity);
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE BookingQuantity IS NULL  returns 0 rows, so all have 1 or more if there are any.