# LINQ to Entities: Summing child value

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have reviewed numerous reports of this error but the solutions I have seen either do not apply or don't work in my situation (or I'm not understanding how to make them work?) so I'm reluctantly posting this in the hope of finding an answer.

I'm submitting the following simple query in L2E:

```
var symbolCover = DataModel.NCoverAnalysisDetail.Where(d => d.IsNew && 
           d.NCoverAnalysis.BuildTime > FromNewDate).Sum(c => c.SymbolCoverage);
```

and it throws the following exception:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

There are no nullable columns on the tables and the SQL (see below) being sent to the database returns 0 (zero), so I can't see what the problem is.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
SUM([Extent1].[SymbolCoverage]) AS [A1]
FROM  [dbo].[NCoverAnalysisDetail] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[NCoverAnalysis] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[NCoverAnalysisID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[IsNew] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[BuildTime] > @p__linq__0)
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 datetime',@p__linq__0='2012-02-17 00:00:00'
```

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076827/linq-error-generic-parameter-or-the-query-must-use-a-nullable-type.  Try using an int? instead of a var for symbolCover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var symbolCover = DataModel.NCoverAnalysisDetail
           .Where(d => d.IsNew && d.NCoverAnalysis.BuildTime > FromNewDate)
           .Sum(c => (int?)c.SymbolCoverage).GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

Comment: thanks this does stop the error - but why?  Where is the _null_ coming in when the underlying field is not nullable and the SQL returns zero?

Comment: There might be no rows to sum, because of the filter